# find indexes of specific values in array (openCL)

Tags: c++, arrays, opencl

I have an array of length 22500 which is filled with 1's and 0's:
{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0}
For the execution of my following iteration, I need to know how many 1's are in that array (very easy 2 step reduction) and more importantly at what positions they are. The positions should be in the format {3,4,6,10} considering my example array above. Is there any smart way to do this in opencl? Copying the array to my host program and running it on the CPU will take too long. Enqueuing a single kernel will take too long as well.

What I would basically like to be able to do is to run 256 workers (one work group) and whenever a worker encounters a '1' it will add the index to the indexes array.

Here is a draft of the kernel that I would like to use:

```
__kernel void findIndexesOfRowsToCecalc(__global int * rowsToRecalc, __global int * lengthOfArray,__global int * indexes,__global int * sum){
int lid = get_local_id(0);
__local int ctr = 0;
__local int sums[256];
int mysum = 0;

for (int i = lid; i < *lengthOfArray; i += get_local_size(0)){
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if (*(rowsToRecalc + i) == 1){
        *(indexes + ctr) = i;
        ctr = ctr + 1;
        mysum = mysum + 1;
    }
}
sums[lid] = mysum;
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

int pmax = get_local_size(0)>>1;
while (pmax>0){
    if (lid < pmax){
        sums[lid] = sums[lid] + sums[lid + pmax];
    }
    pmax = pmax >> 1;
}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

if (lid == 0){
    *sum = sums[0];
}
}
```

My concern is that if two workers encounter a '1' simulatenously, will they attempt to write it to the same position in the indexes array or will the local ctr variable be incremented before that happens? Is there another way to solve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If the number of 1s is low, you can continue with your approach and use `atomic_cmpxchg()`. If it is high, maybe a reduction-filter kernel to remove the zeros, after you have converted the 1s to indexes (with another kernel) would be the way to go.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. The 1's are rather rare so atomic_cmpxchg() is perfect! I will try it out on monday.

However I must admit that I don't completely understand your other suggestion. If the 1's have been converted to the indexes, how would I remove the 0's efficiently? As far as I understand your suggestion I would end up with the same problem where I would have to juggle with indexes. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: A simple approach would be a sort kernel, all the 0s would be at the end of the array, so you have consecutive indexes of the ones position. In addition, ordered.

Comment: That sounds like a really good idea but I am not sure if sorting that big array will take up a lot of computation time, maybe even more than just doing the whole thing on the CPU or with one kernel. It will be easier (and more convenient) to use atomic_cmpxchg(), especially, because I expect to have only few 1's in that array. Is there any situation where atomic_cmpxchg would be a bad idea? I guess if there are a lot of 1's then I would run into lots of read/write conflicts which will slow everything down